# Can I use Intent (or some equivalent) to get a "Share Via" prompt from my Air app running on Android?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, android-intent, share

Is there some way that an Android app written in Air can send data (text, images, etc.) to another Android app, in the way that native apps do through the "Share Via" dialog that appears when the Intent filter is used?

Thanks!

Comment: How are data sent from one android to another one with native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a feature request on Adobe's site for an intents API:
[(feature request for intents API)](http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=EEF3EC13-E28F-41CC-AE7D-D47CE06E03CE)